# android, how to open app in playstore form FCM notification with PendingIntent

Tags: android, google-play

when open playstore programmatically, it could use try/catch

```
try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id="+appName));
            intent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+appName));
            intent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
            startActivity(intent);
    }
```

And when receives FCM message, it will need to put the intent in PendingIntent, and android will do startactivity() when tap the notiffication

```
        Intent intent;
      

        try {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName));
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName));
        }
        intent.setPackage("com.android.vending");

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, nextNotificationId(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        
        ... ... ...
```

it works on the device which has playstore app installed, but does not do anything (when tap on the notification with this PendingIntent), and the `"market://details?id=" + appPackageName` does not cause exception.

Tried and found that on the device which does not have playtore app installed, the following line will open the playstore in browser:

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName));
```

without the line of setting the `com.android.vending` to the intent's package:

```
intent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
```

**So the question is how to check if the playstore app is installed on the device?**
if it can detect that it could conditionally choose the working code.

tried this on the same device, it returns true for com.android.vending

```
private static final String GooglePlayStorePackageNameOld = "com.google.market";
private static final String GooglePlayStorePackageNameNew = "com.android.vending";

void someMethod() {
    PackageManager packageManager = getApplication().getPackageManager();
    List<PackageInfo> packages = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES);
    for (PackageInfo packageInfo : packages) {
        if (packageInfo.packageName.equals(GooglePlayStorePackageNameOld) ||
            packageInfo.packageName.equals(GooglePlayStorePackageNameNew)) {
            googlePlayStoreInstalled = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and the `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Context)` is true as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActivityNotFoundException` is throwed by `startActivity` in case if there was no `Activity` found to run the given Intent.
If you are not calling `startActivity()` on the intent directly you can use [Intent#resolveActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#resolveActivity(android.content.pm.PackageManager)) to verify that an app exists to receive the intent

```
Intent intent;
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName));
if (intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) == null) {
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName));
}
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context, nextNotificationId(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```